# trying to have png image show up in my Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, png, imagecreatefrompng

I'm trying to get an image to show up, but it's just not working. Mind you, this is my very first Ruby app (self-programmed product) and I cloned the Repo, so my apologies in advance if I'm not providing all the required information from the get-go or missing a rather simple oversight.

Here is my screenshot of my image not displaying:

[image]

I created the graphic in Illustrator and exported it was a png. I then added it to the right project folder. The image is called AIQtshirt.png and here's the code snippet:

```
 {
  'count' => 15,
  'html' => 'AutonomIQ<br>T-shirt',
  'class' => 'three',
  'image' => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(
    'refer/AIQtshirt.png') 
  }
```

In fact, when I use the image that was there there before (from the Repo I cloned), it works. This image is called truman.png and it's in the same folder that I put the AIQtshirt.png file:

[image]

Here's the code snippet from using the initial placeholder that was in the repo when I cloned it:

```
{
  'count' => 15,
  'html' => 'AutonomIQ<br>T-shirt',
  'class' => 'three',
  'image' => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(
    'refer/truman.png')
}
```

If it's easier to look at the repo it can be referenced here. https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr

I can imagine there's something I'm forgetting to do in another folder of the repo.

Here's the string I got when I edited the repo with the code provided in the comments:

[image]

[image: image of source code of broken image]

[image: Image of the source code of the image originally in the repo]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update: Here is the code:

```
<% stops.each do |stop| %>
    <li class="product brandon <% if stop["selected"] %>selected<% end %> <% if stop["class"] == 'five' %>last<% end %>">
      <div class="circle"><%= stop["count"] %></div>
      <div class="sep"></div>
      <p><%= stop["html"].html_safe %></p>

      <div class="tooltip">
         <img src="<%= stop["image"] %>" height="254">
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi sjmario38, is it possible to share the path to the image just to be sure that it is in the right place?

Comment: HI @Abhinay my apologies in advance for my naivety. By path, do you mean the folder where my image is located in the GitHub repo? If so it's: /Documents/GitHub/prelaunchr/app/assets/images/refer/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to debug**

A way to debug this would be to edit your `app/views/users/refer.html.erb` to show the image url visibly on your page. You should find this piece (assuming it relates to image you are not able to see):

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <img src="<%= stop["image"] %>" height="254">
</div>
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  My img url as seen by rails is: <%= stop["image"] %> 
  <br/> Hm, is this where my image is? Have I made a typo? :)
  <img src="<%= stop["image"] %>" height="254">
</div>
```

**What worked**

Since I didn't want to let this hanging unanswered I went and cloned `pre-launcher` app myself and was able to make the image display.
So, I'll assume you're running your dev server using `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` and that everything from README file of the pre-launcher repository went well for you (e.g. rake db:create, rake db:migrate)

So, here is what I did. I took some random shaver photo from the internet and named it `fancy-shaver.png` and saved it in:
`app/assets/images/refer` folder.

Then I edited `app/models/user.rb` (just the first referal step) and put this:

```
 REFERRAL_STEPS = [
    {
      'count' => 5,
      'html' => 'Fancy shaver',
      'class' => 'two',
      'image' =>  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(
        'refer/fancy-shaver.png') # <- this is what I changed
    },
    {
      'count' => 10,
      'html' => 'Truman Handle<br>w/ Blade',
      'class' => 'three',
      'image' => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(
        'refer/truman@2x.png')
    },
    # ... the rest I didn't touch
```

Then I opened, `http://localhost:5000/refer-a-friend` and same as you I experienced the image was missing.
Then I just did: `CTRL+C` where my server was running and started it again.
The image was visible after that. And below is what I got:

[image]

**If it doesn't work still**

*Advice*: when things go south, especially when learning something new, sometimes the best thing to do is to restart everything (clone app in a new folder) and do exactly the steps that worked (e.g. you can try what I did above after following the app readme).

Comment: Wow, I think it's working. I was able to add that little snippet to test/debug and that string showed up in the app viewer... 

Where do you suggest I go from here? All of images have this snippet.

Comment: can you share the string you got by editing the question?

Comment: for sure - I attached the image to the question of how the app reacted. The sentence you suggested to type showed up in the picture.

Comment: can you check page source in browser and add the part around that image instead of the screenshot...

Comment: Hi @draganstankovic - I've inspected the image (the one that was there before and in the repo)  in the browser and it shows us as:

<div class="tooltip">
"
       My img url as seen by rails is? Have I made a typo :)

"
<img src="/assets/refer/truman-7812276... .png" height="254"> == $0
</div>

The image that I tried to put in it's place still shows up as a broken image and the source shows up as:


<div class="tooltip">
"
       My img url as seen by rails is? Have I made a typo :)

"
<img src="/assets/refer/welcometotheclub.png" height="254"> == $0
</div>

Comment: I added the edit section in my answer, would be nice if you could share (as edit of your question what are the modifications you have made). Specifically, this `... == $0` this part that you shared in comment seems weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210916/discussion-between-sjmario38-and-draganstankovic).